# I want to annotate (add letters eg A and B) to the resulting 2 Kaplan Meier curves plots using splots and survminer in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survminer

I need to add letters eg A and B to the resulting 2 Kaplan Meier curves plots

code

```
library(survminer)
# Fit survival curves
require("survival")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
# List of ggsurvplots
require("survminer")
splots <- list()
splots[[1]] <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE, ggtheme = theme_minimal())
splots[[2]] <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE, ggtheme = theme_grey())

# Arrange multiple ggsurvplots and print the output
arrange_ggsurvplots(splots, print = TRUE,
  ncol = 2, nrow = 1, risk.table.height = 0.4)

# Arrange and save into pdf file
res <- arrange_ggsurvplots(splots, print = FALSE)
ggsave("myfile.pdf", res, width = 15, height = 15, units = "cm")
```

So I need the resulting plot like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `ggsurvplot(...,risk.table=TRUE,...)` creates a list that holds a plot  and a table. You can access the plot with `splots[[...]]$plot` and then add a figure label with `labs(tag="A")`.

```
library(survminer)
# Fit survival curves
require("survival")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
# List of ggsurvplots
splots <- list()
splots[[1]] <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE, ggtheme = theme_minimal()  ) 
splots[[2]] <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE, ggtheme = theme_grey()) 

# access the plot objects and add a tag with labs()
splots[[1]]$plot<-splots[[1]]$plot + labs(tag="A")
splots[[2]]$plot<-splots[[2]]$plot + labs(tag="B")

# Arrange multiple ggsurvplots and print the output
arrange_ggsurvplots(splots, print = TRUE,
                    ncol = 2, nrow = 1, risk.table.height = 0.4)

# Arrange and save into pdf file
res <- arrange_ggsurvplots(splots, print = FALSE)
ggsave("myfile.pdf", res, width = 15, height = 15, units = "cm")
```

[image]

Comment: @gregor.fausto Thx a lot. Greatly appreciated. upvoted. Please let me know if there is a way to control this annotation"A" and "B" font size.

Comment: You can control the font size of the tags with `theme(plot.tag=element_text(...))`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243514/ggplot2-change-title-size for an example of how to use `element_text()`.